# pagedown HTML resume - how to increase font size and reduce margins

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, pagedown

I am using the `pagedown` template resume, which is accessible by starting a new R markdown file and choosing "From Template" and "HTML Resume".

I have pasted the YAML header below.

```yaml
---
title: "Lijia Yu's resume"
author: Lijia Yu
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_resume:
    # set it to true for a self-contained HTML page but it'll take longer to render
    self_contained: false
# uncomment this line to produce HTML and PDF in RStudio:
#knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---
```

The normal adding of `fontsize: 12pt` or `geometry: margin=1cm` doesn't work for me.

I did try adding some CSS (which I don't know too well), but it overrides the template and I want the formatting of the template to stay intact, just larger font and reduced margins.

I also found this snippet that removes the sidebar on the 2nd page. I'd love to incorporate this code as well:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.pagedjs_page:not(:first-of-type) {
  --sidebar-width: 0rem;
  --sidebar-background-color: #ffffff;
  --main-width: calc(var(--content-width) - var(--sidebar-width));
  --decorator-horizontal-margin: 0.2in;
}
```
````

How to keep the general formatting of the HTML resume with larger font, smaller margins, and incorporate the code to remove the sidebar on the 2nd page?

Comment: I figured how to change the margins and font size of the resume template. In your working directory, when you create a resume template, a folder is created "[File Name]_files". My R Markdown file name was called "2022_08_06_R", so the folder automatically created was "2022_08_06_R_files". Go into the "paged-0.18" folder, "CSS", and then you see the "resume.css". That is the template's CSS formatting.

Comment: You'll have to create another CSS file in your working dir to complement the "resume.css", name it "override.css". 

Add in YAML

`add "output:
  pagedown::html_resume:
    css: 
    - override.css #complement resume.css 
    - resume #original css`

You'll have to add additional CSS to the "override.css" if you want changes to be made on top of the resume.css.

Comment: E.g. in my "override.css", I added:

`* {
    /* Override default margins*/
    --pagedjs-margin-right: 0.1in;
    --pagedjs-margin-left: 0.1in;
    --pagedjs-margin-top: 0.1in;
    --pagedjs-margin-bottom: 0.1in;
  }
  
  :root{
    --sidebar-width: 11rem; /* side bar width */
    --root-font-size: 15.5pt;
  }
  
  
.aside{
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}`

On top of the original "resume.css", I was able to change the margins, reduce the sidebar width, and change the root font size